# Start scheduled task immediately after it over runs window

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task set to run hourly. Sometimes this task will take slightly longer than an hour to run. How can I set it so that if it hasn't finished before the next scheduled time it will run immediately after it finishes. I have tried selecting the option to 'Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed' but this does not seem to be working.